# Collation conflict in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, union

I am trying to make a Union between two tables, and I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "Chinese_Hong_Kong_Stroke_90_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
>   in the UNION operation.

The types of the columns are the same (string goes to string, etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the collation for the table.  Here are the steps to do so:

1. In SQL server management studio, right click on the database in question and choose properties.
2. In the properties dialogue box, choose "Options" in the left pane
3. In the right pane, the current collation will be listed against Collation label.
4. Change to desired and apply.

PS: Ensure all components accessing the database are stopped while doing the above. Failing this will cause an error to pop-up.

Here is where I found this information (2nd to last thread):
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=77212

Comment: Thanks!! So if I'll change it in the database properties it won't cause problems in Linq as well?

Comment: hmm that's a good question :)  It shouldn't, Once you make the change you may just need to refresh your table in your project that is using linq. But I would highly recommend making a copy of the table first just in case you do have problems you can switch back easily.